# Marble/Stones online photo stock?

Tags: stock-photography

I am working on a brochure for Marble/Stones/Granite dealer. That dealer doesn't have the photos of his materials in high res. So I've been trying to look for a marble online photo stock where I can just download and buy some high res images (+4000px WxH) but my bad luck! nothing was actually interesting.

Shutterstock, istockphoto and gettyimages are not really specialized in the marble; any suggestions/references would be appreciated. I would be happy to have  photo stock with some description also to make sure that the name is relative to the images given..

here are couples of some materials I am searching for:

Arbescato, Armani Grey, Afyon White, Armani Brown, Azul Macaubus, Azul Sodalite, Belgium, lack, BerdiglioImperiale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know nothing about marbles – but often the supplier/manufacturer has access to good photos. You could try that.

Another option would be to check competitors. Do they have their own photos? If so, did they create them themselves or get them online? You could use Google's "Search by Image" feature to see if those photos appear anywhere else on the web.

Comment: You're 100% correct but the point is the images I am looking for needs to exceed the  web resolution mostly used, and in order to maintain the best quality on the brochure and the printed material all of the photos should be at least 300 DPI regardless of the size:d where I consider the size as a second issue... thanks.

Comment: @KQI - look at texture maps for 3D programs if you don't need to see slab sides.